# Can we make nested routes better in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, nested-routes

I have deeply nested routes in my Laravel5.2 app like so:

```
country
country.state
country.state.county
country.state.county.city
country.state.county.city.child
country.state.county.city.child.status
```

this forces me to include ids of all the parents to child method params which is a nuisance to me.

How can this be improved?

I don't think I need to show any code to sort this out. Do I?